# Differences between Share Dialog, Feed Dialog and share_open_graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a project where I need users to share content via app.

After that I will need to track how many shares were made per day.

Now I can share a link using three different functions as follow:

```
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
        hashtag: '#myhash',
    }, function(response){console.log(response)});


    FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.likes',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object:'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples',
        })
    }, function(response){
        // Debug response (optional)
        console.log(response);
    });


    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
        ref: 'ref1, ref2'
    }, function(response){console.log(response)});
```

The only differences I can see is that using share I can add hashtags and feed dialog I can add refs. Visually they all look the same on the feed...

Will any of these be more benefitial than the others assuming later I want to search and analyse the shared content? (for example, different hashtags and / or different sources like mobile / web)?

Comment: hashtags? you mean, what user messages were being used while sharing? that´s impossible to know. also, share callbacks are pretty much void nowadays. they will also be called when the user just closes the share popup without sharing. you can only check out app insights for information about shares. no matter which dialog, manual share tracking is impossible.

Comment: _“After that I will need to track how many shares were made per day.”_ - for what exact purpose? Keep in mind that incentivizing users to share by promising them any kind of reward is not allowed by platform policy - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.4